# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display the name of the category, but I get this error:

```php
BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()
```

AdminController.php

```php
public function gamelist()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $home = DB::table('products')->with(['categories']);
    return view('admin.gamelist', ['categories' => $categories, 'home' => $home, 'mode' => 'admin']);
}
```

Product.php

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
}
```

gamelist.blade.php

```php
@foreach ($homes as $home)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $home->id }}</td>
      <td>{{ $home->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $home->categories->name}}</td>
      <td>{{ $home->price }} €</td>
```

Can someone help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with` is used to eager-load Eloquent relationships. By calling `DB::table`, you decided to use the query builder instead, and this one can't use Eloquent relationships.

You should replace

```php
$home = DB::table('products')->with(['categories']);
```

by

```php
$home = Product::with('categories')->get();
```