# Laravel with() method gives: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

When executing the following query:

`$jobs = DB::table('jobs')->with('companies:name')->where('published', 0)->get();`

I get:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with().

I want all my jobs where `published == 0`, with the `companies name` from a relation. I do not see why with is undefined here, could you guys help me out?

Comment: `with()` is an Eloquent builder method, not a Database Query Builder method.

You should define your Jobs model and a relation on that.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to laravel and somehow could not figure this out. Was my question really that bad? :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62021427/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builderwith)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want with `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` you can do it like:

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
    ->select('jobs.*', 'companies.name')
    ->join('companies', 'jobs.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->where('jobs.published', 0)
    ->get();
```

But it's better to use [Laravel Eloquent ORM](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent) as it maps your database, instead accessing direct by the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#main-content).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `with` on Database Query Builder. It can only be used with Eloquent Models. But this will help

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
    ->join('companies', 'jobs.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->select('jobs.*', 'companies.name')
    ->where('jobs.published', 0)
    ->get();
```

I will suggest you use Eloquent ORM. You will create a model named `Job`, and another named `Company`. Then, relate both tables.

In the Job model class, you will create a relationship with the Company like this

```
public function company(){

    return $this->belongTo(Company::class);

}
```

In the Company model class, you will create a relationship with the Job like this

```
public function jobs(){

    return $this->hasMany(Job::class);

}
```

I hope this helps